# Get Querydsl Oracle Rowid when we have more than one table

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, jpql, querydsl

I have a problem when using `OracleGrammar.rowid` in querydsl where we need to join multiple tables and the rowid column is getting ambigous in the query. i searched ways to specify the table of rowid and still could not found an answer, please help me

```
query.select(OracleGrammar.rowid, Q1.a, Q2.b).from( Q1, Q2)
```

`OracleGrammar.rowid` => ambigous column

Thank you.

Comment: What do you need the rowid for, when you join multiple tables?

Comment: Actually im converting an old query without breaking it's fuctionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a template using [`stringTemplate()`](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.1.0/apidocs/com/querydsl/core/types/dsl/Expressions.html#stringTemplate-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-):

```
Expressions.stringTemplate("{0}.rowid", Q1.a)
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! If you have any good references please share

Comment: @MaxExplode: What do you mean by references?

Comment: @MaxExplode: Well, since you're asking, a good reference is https://www.jooq.org ;-) (since I work on that competitor product)

Comment: Ohh, thank you very much for helping me anyway jooq community edition is not supporting oracle thats why im using querydsl

Comment: @MaxExplode: Good luck then!

Comment: Thank you again !